# Using UART to USB on a PIC24f

Tags: pic, uart, mplabx

**Disclaimer:** New to PICs, need things dumbed down to an extent until I start to figure things out.

I'm trying to set up a UART connection on the PIC24fJ32GA002 to an FTDI which will then go to my computer for debugging, and later to the HC-12 for wireless transmission. However I'm struggling to understand exactly how to go about it.

### Hardware

I'm more familiar with this. It looks like my chip is using the peripheral pins to for UART, so I have pin 6 (RP2) as RX, and pin7 (RP3) as TX, then ground of course and no VCC as they are each powered independently. RTS and CTS are not yet hooked up. I'm curious about those, do, or when do, I need them? I know they are for flow control, "Clear to Send" and "Request To Send", but not sure how the PIC handles them.

### Software

The datasheet does give a process which I was generally following

[image]

So with UART using peripheral pins, I need to first setup these pins right? According to the datasheet, this is done by:

```
// Unlock Registers
__builtin_write_OSCCONL(OSCCON & 0xBF);

// Configure Input Functions (Table 10-2))
// Assign U1RX To Pin RP0
RPINR18bits.U1RXR = 0;

// Assign U1CTS To Pin RP1
RPINR18bits.U1CTSR = 1;

// Configure Output Functions (Table 10-3)
// Assign U1TX To Pin RP2
RPOR1bits.RP2R = 3;

// Assign U1RTS To Pin RP3
RPOR1bits.RP3R = 4;

// Lock Registers
__builtin_write_OSCCONL(OSCCON | 0x40);
```

So I want to break down what's going on here, this unlocks the registers using `__builtin_write_OSCCONL(OSCCON & 0xBF);`, I cannot find info on this anywhere, and would like to understand what its doing, it unlocks some registers? What registers? Why are they locked? Anyways, then it actually assigns the pins.
Now RPINR are for setting inputs to the RP pins, and RPOR for output as far as I understand. But I'm not understanding how its actually selecting a pin. So say for RX, we will have to look at RPINR18 because its the one that deals with RX for UART1, then it looks like we have the option of 0-4 for RPINR18bits.U1RXR

[image: Peripheral Pin Registers]

Then I would expect that RPINR18bits.U1RXR = 0, would set it to RP0, but this breaks down when we look at setting TX, TX doesn't even show up on the register map, so I'm thinking I'm missing some information here.

Now I was a little confused by the instructions, because writing appropriate data, parity, and stop bits are done in UART1 register right? If I set this it would also enable UART1, unless I decide to set that particular bit later. So I'll ignore that for now.

According to the data sheet I would have to give it a baud rate? In the datasheet there's a  formula to get your desired baud rate, but it doesn't elaborate on how to actually add it. Do you set U1BRG to whatever number  you calculated?

Then setting interrupts, I have absolutely no idea where to start here. Do I absolutely need them? Where should I look?

Next I would have to set the UART1 control register values.
So that would be something like `UART1 = 1000001000011000`, looking at the UARTx control register page on the datasheet. I think this should also able UART.

Now UART is active, then if I want to write anything,

- I enable UTXEN by `U1STAbits.UTXEN = 1;`
- Set the lower half of U1TXREG to the byte I want to send
- Repeat until all bytes transmitted
- Disable UTXEN by `U1STAbits.UTXEN = 0;`

If this is the case, then how do I know when I can send the next byte? Interrupts?

### Summary

- Whats the deal with CTS and RTS,
- Where can I find information on the locking and unlocking of registers?
- How do I actually assign a peripheral to the correct pin?
- How to actually assign the correct baud rate
- Where should I look for interrupts
- How do I know when to write another byte to U1TXREG?
- Overall what am I missing in the process?

Sorry this is a long one. Tried to get as much information as I could myself. Maybe I'm making this overly complicated. Example code would be great!

Comment: I am slightly worried about you intending to connect two devices together that have separate power supplies. How do you intend to handle a situation where one chip is powered and the other isn't?

Comment: @Justme well one is my laptop and the other is the pic, the laptop will always be on, and f the pic isnt on nothing should happen. I could always just power the PIC through laptop->usb->ftdi if I wanted, I just didnt

Comment: I am not talking about the laptop or USB connection. I am talking about the FTDI chip TXD/RXD connection to PIC chip RXD/TXD. If one of the chips is unpowered, the powered chip TXD output pin will try to power the unpowered chip via the RXD input pin. So the "nothing should happen" part is not true.

Comment: @Justme Oh I see, the FTDI has a soldered USB connection, so the only time it wont be powered is if its not pugged in. Should I wire up the power line as well? It has a 3.3v jumper, but what happens if both are on and being powered at the same time through each of their sources?

Comment: Connecting two power supplies together is generally considered a bad idea too. One option is to make the whole device bus powered via USB, or self-powered via external supply. But it depends on what you want to do and if the system can be modified.